# sql - beginning of hour, month etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I know how to get in SQL (SQL Server) the current date, but with the beginning of the day:

```
select dateadd(DAY, datediff(day, 0, getdate()),0) 
(result:2009-09-17 00:00:00.000)
```

**I need** to get (in SQL) the current date with the beginning of this hour.
For example: 2009-09-17 17:00:00 (I don't care about the exact format)

and **I need** to get the current date but with the beginning of this month:
For example: 2009-09-01 00:00:00.000 (I don't care about the exact format)

Can you help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Just adapt your current start of day code!

All you want is start of month, start of hour. Its just the same...

```
select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()),0) 

select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, getdate()),0)
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
CAST(CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 12):

The shortest one is: `CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select DATEADD(hh,17,dateadd(DAY, datediff(day, 0, getdate()),0))

SELECT CAST('01 ' + CAST(DATENAME(MM, getdate()) AS VARCHAR(15)) + CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(5)) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: first: thanks. second: you explicitly put the time now (17 in your first query, 01 in your second query) . I dont want to put this numbers I need the current hour. the current month.

Comment: Change the 17 to DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()) which gets you the current hour

and the 01 is for start of month, did i misunderstand?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try this

For day: `select CONVERT( datetime, convert( varchar(8), getdate(), 112))`

For month: `select CONVERT( datetime, convert( varchar(6), getdate(), 112)+ '01')`

For year: `select CONVERT( datetime, convert( varchar(4), getdate(), 112)+ '0101')`

Answer (score 1):

From SQL Server 2022 you can use [`DATETRUNC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for both these needs.

> I need to get the current date with the beginning of this
> hour. For example: 2009-09-17 17:00:00

```
SELECT DATETRUNC(hour, GETDATE())
```

> and I need to get the current date but with the beginning of this
> month: For example: 2009-09-01 00:00:00.000

```
SELECT DATETRUNC(month, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

For postgres

SELECT date_trunc('month', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40+00')

another variant

SELECT date_trunc('hour', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 2001-02-16 20:00:00

SELECT date_trunc('year', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 2001-01-01 00:00:00

SELECT date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40+00');
Result: 2001-02-16 00:00:00-05

SELECT date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40+00', 'Australia/Sydney');
Result: 2001-02-16 08:00:00-05

SELECT date_trunc('hour', INTERVAL '3 days 02:47:33');
Result: 3 days 02:00:00

Comment: The question has nothing to do with postgres. If you had a different issue, write a new question and tag it with the relevant technologies. If you have an answer for said question then you can also answer your own question